# Merge {warnings} and {warning}

Tags: discussion, tagging

There does not seem to be any relevant difference of the tags [warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warnings) and [warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning) and neither are heavily used. What about merging them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are already merged. [warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning) is a synonym for [warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warnings). If somebody uses [warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning) it would be automatically mapped to [warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warnings).

If we don't keep singular tags, they would possibly be recreated sooner or later and we would have to merge again.